# What's wrong with this HTTP request?

Tags: http, xbee

I am sending the following HTTP request:

```
POST /input/8dZ8bgapvjfYzmwWno6W.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: data.sparkfun.com
Phant-Private-Key: pz5ga4pkydHgpEb8v608
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 7

temp=44
```

In my code, I am sending it using UART tx requests to the xbee module, for which the translates to:

```
POST /input/8dZ8bgapvjfYzmwWno6Wr.txt HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: data.sparkfun.com\r\n
Phant-Private-Key: pz5ga4pkydHgpEb8v608\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
Content-Length: 7\r\n
\r\n
temp=44
```

This is to communicate to the phant dataserver at data.sparkfun.com, and it responds with the following data:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>
Your browser sent an invalid request.
</body></html>
```

Comment: This is not a TCP packet, or an IP packet, or a TCP segment. It is an HTTP request and response. Wifi is irrelevant. You need to show what the line terminator characters are.

Comment: @EJP can you pleas tell me what "line terminator character is?"

Comment: @Sush: you did not explain HOW you are sending the request.  Are you using an HTTP library?  Are you using manual socket API calls? If the latter, are you using `CR` (0x0D), `LF` (0x0A) or `CRLF` (0x0D 0x0A) at the end of each line that you send?  HTTP requires `CRLF`.  Outside of that, there is nothing wrong with the rest of the request, although I find it odd that you are `POST`ing a webform submission to a `.txt` file instead of a processing script, such as ASP, PHP, CGI/Perl, etc.  Are you sure you have the correct URL to `POST` to?

Comment: You haven't modified it to show any details of (a) what software you're using to generate this request or (b) why you are posting to a .txt file. (b) is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: @EJP If I enter this into the addressbar of my browser:
data.sparkfun.com/input/8dZ8bgapvjfYzmwWno6Wr.txt?private_key=pz5ga4pkydHgpEb8v608&temp=123

It works fine to add the data, so I think the .txt file is correct

Comment: I am using an XBEE Wifi module. I have connected to it using XCTU and am just sending the HTTP request to it through UART bytes (the XCTU software does this)

Comment: Your browser executes a GET request. That does not prove it's a correct URL target for a POST. You still haven't stated how you generate the HTTP request. Telling us you put it through one subsystem then another doesn't explain where the bytes originally came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: 
The packet is correct. 
While configuring the Xbee Wifi module using XCTU, I had to give the correct port numbers of the server and client Xbee, which were wrong. 
Server was 80, client was any port I think.